# How to persist asp.net textbox in a cookie within asp.net updatepanel?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, cookies, updatepanel

I have an asp.net 3.5 update panel and I have a few textboxes that users enter information into that I want to persist when they return next time.  I've tried various approaches to persisting the cookie from the click event of a button (postback trigger) etc. but I believe the problem is that there is no response header access during the ajax callback?  Not sure!

How can I persist values of a textbox to a cookie that exist within the content of an asp.net update panel?

Thank you.

Comment: When you say "return next time," do you mean during the same session?  A later visit to the site?  Immediately after postback?

Comment: Another day, not in session.  Close browser, come back another day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just creating a serializable class that I persist.